# fetch to array from mysql while

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to fetch columns to array and then export it to excel. Here is my code. $addizi and $teldizi are arrays pulled from second table.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'");
        $i=1;
        $addizi = array();
        $teldizi = array();
        while($oku=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    $transida = $oku['id'];
    $result3it = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table2 where transid = '$transida'");
            while($oku3it=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3it))
            {

                $addizi[] = $oku3it['name'];
                $teldizi[] = $oku3it['tel'];


            }
            $row = array($addizi, $oku['from'],$oku['to'], $teldizi, date('d-m-Y', strtotime($oku['dateTr'])), $oku['timeTr']);
            $excel->addRow($row);
    $i++;
    }

    $excel->finalize();
```

The code exports excel file but data in second while does not exist. It does not export $addizi and $teldizi.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add `$addizi` and `$teldizi` as type element? From the code provided, I can only guess that a numeric or string value might be what makes more sense. Give `implode(',', $addizi)` on the line of assigning it to `$row` a try.

Comment: yes it worked :) thank you very much

Comment: In addition to the above, please be aware that your code is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent this, making sure to bind your inputs to variables. You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: @GkNx Glad I could help. I provided my comment as an answer. Please accept is as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already posted in the comment section. Here is the solution:

Instead of providing `$addizi` and `$teldizi` as array to `$row`, provide them as strings by calling `implode(',', $addziz)` and `implode(',', $teldizi)`.